# How to set a Textbox value as double and make is empty without using " " in VB.net windows form application?

Tags: vb.net

Here is the code

```
Public Partial Class MainForm
Public Sub New()
    ' The Me.InitializeComponent call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
    Me.InitializeComponent()

    '
    ' TODO : Add constructor code after InitializeComponents
    '
End Sub

Sub Label4Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Sub Button2Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim poundInAKg As Double = 2.20462
    Dim KGInAPound As Double = 0.453592
    If pound.Text = " " Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill atleast one value Kilo or Pound : ")
    End If

    kilo.Text = Val(pound.Text) * 0.453592
    'pound.Text = Val(kilo.Text / 2.20462 )


End Sub

Sub MainFormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
End Class
```

The error is Implicit conversion from 'Double' to 'String'. (BC42016) 
Please help

Comment: you're trying to put a double value into a text box which expects a string value. Not sure of the VB syntax but something like Convert.ToString(Val(pound.Text) * 0.453592) should do you.

Comment: first things first, turn on option Strict; then dont use `Val` - `Double.TryParse()` is more appropriate since the text control can have non numerics in it

Comment: @Plutonix That;s was the thing Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method to try to convert the user input (a string) to a double value, then, if the conversion is successful, execute the moltiplication and reconvert everything back to a string

```
Dim poundInAKg As Double = 2.20462
Dim KGInAPound As Double = 0.453592
Dim poundVal As Double
if double.TryParse(pound.Text, poundVal) Then
    kilo.Text = (poundVal * 0.453592).ToString()
else
    MessageBox.Show("Please fill atleast one value Kilo or Pound : ")
End If
```